# What causes the typescript Module has no exported member .ts(2305) error and how do you fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my first time using typescript with React and I'm have a tremendous amount of trouble with the typescript `Module has no exported member .ts(2305)` error. Here are 2 examples of this happening:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Error:

```
'"react-router-dom"' has no exported member named 'Routes'. Did you mean 'Route'?ts(2724)
```

And here

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
```

Error:

```
Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'useNavigate'.ts(2305)
```

Last example:

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

Error:

```
Module '"react-native-vector-icons"' has no exported member 'MaterialCommunityIcons'.ts(2305)
```

Here is my package.json file if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/history": "2.0.45",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "community": "^0.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "icons": "^1.0.0",
    "material": "^0.4.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-vector-icons": "^0.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

What can I do to fix this issue when it comes up? I'm not exactly asking about these 3 particular issues, but how to solve the `Module has no exported member .ts(2305)` error because it seems to come up often.

What I have read a couple times and have tried to do is install the type definitions (I think?) like this:

`yarn add @types/react-router-dom` and `yarn add @types/react-router` and finally `yarn add @types/react-native-vector-icons` and trying simply `yarn install` but this has never solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a general error, it is a very specific one. This error tells you that you are trying to import something that doesn't exist.

And the answer for each depends on what you are importing.

- `Routes` is not a named export of `react-router-dom`. Nowhere [in the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) is the the characters `<Routes`. I dont know what you think you're importing, but you probably wanted something else.
- `MaterialCommunityIcons` is not a named export of `react-native-vector-icons`. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#tabbar) you need to import that like this:

  ```
  import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
  ```
- `useNavigate` is not a named export of `react-router`. [The documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) lists `useNavigation`. Did you mean to import that instead?

As you can see, there is not a one size fits all solution. You must consult the documentation and try to find what you want to import and ensure that you get the right thing.

Comment: Ah I did not realize this. Thank you for the explanation Alex!

Answer (score 23):

If you're upgrading from v5 and see this issue, I removed the `@types/react-router-dom` dependency and it fixed this issue, since types for v6 were shipped with `react-router-dom`. The `@types` dependency itself wasn't bumped from v5.

Comment: This was the answer for me, thanks so much.

Answer (score 17):

Restarting the typescript server worked for me:

`ctrl+shift+p` > `Typescript: Restart TS server` (click enter)

Answer (score 5):

well for instans react-router-dom version 5 the one in your package json does not have Routes, version 6 is the one with Routes. here you can find more info https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start